# On the solution of Poisson equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, poissons-equation

Given $f\in\mathcal{C}_{c}^2(\Bbb R^n)$ (i.e. twice real-differentiable with compact support) I'm in trouble with the following passage
$$
\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{|y|>\delta}|y|^{2-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\right)\,dy
=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{S_{j\delta}^+-S_{j\delta}^-}|y|^{2-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\,dy'\\
+(2-n)\int_{|y|>\delta}\frac{y_j}{|y|^{n}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\,dy
$$
where $y=(y_j,y')$, i.e. $y'\in\Bbb R^{n-1}$ denotes the remaining coordinates of $y$, the ones different from $y_j$ and
$$
S_{j\delta}^+:=\{y\in\Bbb R^n\;:\;|y|=\delta,\;y_j>0\}\\
S_{j\delta}^-:=\{y\in\Bbb R^n\;:\;|y|=\delta,\;y_j<0\}\;\;.
$$

Now, this is a passage of the proof that $v(x)=-c_n|\cdot|^{2-n}\ast f(x)$ is a solution of the Poisson equation $\Delta v=f$ when $n\ge3$.
Observe that $f$ is initially a function of the variable $x$; then the derivatives you see, were previously outside the integral and they were taken wrt $x$; then, once taken them inside, we must notice that 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f(x-y)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}f(x-y)
$$

I won't write down all details, otherwise the post would become too long. However, what I tried is to write

$$
\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{|y|>\delta}|y|^{2-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\right)\,dy
=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{\Bbb R^n}|y|^{2-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\right)\chi_{E_{\delta}}\,dy
$$
where
\begin{align*}
E_{\delta}
:&=\{y=(y_j,y')\in\Bbb R^n\;:\;y_j^2+|y'|^2>\delta^2\}\\
&=\{|y_j|>\sqrt{\delta^2-|y'|^2},\;|y'|\le\delta\}\sqcup\{|y'|>\delta\}
\end{align*}
from which the last integral can be expressed as
$$
\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{|y'|\le\delta}\left[\int_{|y_j|>\sqrt{\delta^2-|y'|^2}}|y|^{2-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\right)\,dy_j\right]\,dy'+\\
+\int_{|y'|>\delta}\left[\int_{\Bbb R}|y|^{2-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}f(x-y)\right)\,dy_j\right]\,dy'
$$

now integrating by parts the (unique) integral over $\Bbb R$, remembering $f$ is a compact support and the detail of the signs exposed above we should achieve the second part of RHS of the initial equality, since it seems reasonable to think that
$$
\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{|y'|>\delta}\int_{\Bbb R}=
\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{|y|>\delta}\;\;.
$$
But for the first part I'm really in trouble; there must a mistake somewhere, since the integral is done wrt $y'\in\Bbb R^{n-1}$ but the domain seems to be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$. I tried to integrate by parts even this integral, but even adjusting the domain I can't obtain the same integrand function.

I worked on it for a couple of days. Can someone help me please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following is a "high level" proof of integration by parts, using differential forms. The version you want is in some sense "dual" to this one (as it uses vector fields).

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary $\partial M$, $\alpha\in\Omega^k(M)$, and $\beta\in\Omega^{n-k-1}(M)$, where $0\le k< n$. Then by Stokes' theorem we have
$$\int_{\partial M}\alpha\wedge\beta = \int_Md(\alpha\wedge\beta) = \int_Md\alpha\wedge\beta + (-1)^k\int_M\alpha\wedge d\beta,$$
therefore, we have the formula
$$\int_Md\alpha\wedge\beta = \int_{\partial M}\alpha\wedge\beta - (-1)^k\int_M\alpha\wedge d\beta.$$
Notice that the boundary term is given by integration on the boundary.

---

In your case, you have $M=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid\|y\|\ge\delta\}$, $\partial M$ is given by the sphere of radius $\delta$. You only need to identify the two differential forms and unwind the definitions to get to the formula you gave.

Comment: Robert:
 Many thanks! This is surely interesting but my teacher did that in an elementary way, which is the one I want to understand. Now I'm finish to edit my post, in order to explain what my attempt was, so you will understand what is the way I followed, and you will surely can give me some useful hint in a couple minutes. Thanks again